# Histogram equalization on non-image data

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a matrix containing negative and positive values:

[image: a sample matrix]

I succeed to plot its pdf using this command:

```
[n,xout] = hist(A(:), 256);
pdf = n/numel(A);
figure; stem(xout, pdf, 'marker', 'none');
```

unfortunately I couldn't use `unique(A)` instead of `256` because it returns values of my matrix with repetitions!

this is pdf: [pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGCBm.jpg)
How can I do histogram equalization? I computed cumulative sum of pdf using this command:

```
ind = find(pdf == max(pdf));

cdf1 = cumsum(pdf(ind:end));
cdf2 = cumsum(pdf(ind-1:-1:1));

cdf = [flipud(cdf2); cdf1];

figure; stem(xout, cdf, 'marker', 'none');
```

and the resulted cdf is:[cdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxkYg.jpg)

is it true? if yes, what should i do after that? and finally how can i transform equalized histogram to equalized image (matrix)?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about `histogram` or `hist` in previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

If X is your matrix you can simply do:

```
[y, elements] = hist(X(:), unique(X));
stem(elements, y);
```

and you have your histogram

Comment: thank you MingiuX, but why unique(X)? I used 256 instead of unique(X) in argument and get a histogram like that of imhist with negative distribution.

Comment: Using 256 instead of unique(X) you are creating an `elements` vector of 256 elements, so you are dividing your x-axis in 256 different values and giving a weight only to those values you can also find in `X` matrix. With unique(X), instead, you obtain an `elements` vector containing only `X` matrix elements considered only one time (they are elements you are giving a weight different from 0). If this answer isn't clear, try to print your `elements` vector for both cases and you will understand.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.